# What is the purpose of 'main.js' and 'App.vue' in a Vue.js application?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I don't understand the exact purpose of each file.

Suppose I want to add authentication code. Where should I place it, in *main.js* or *App.vue*?

Comment: `main.js` contains the JavaScript to initialise a Vue app. `App.vue` contains the root component of a Vue app.

Answer (score 52):

I believe you might be missing on some of the basics behind the structure of Vue.js and where and/or how to put in functionality like authentication. It might be worth going through [their introduction](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html) again to solidify your knowledge.

To answer more directly, when you run a Vue.js application you need to have a basic HTML page (like *index.html*) as an entry point and the initialisation for your Vue.js application loaded in a `<script>` in that page.

When you write a Vue.js application you can choose to do it in pure JavaScript, in TypeScript or in the .vue component format which combines the HTML, CSS and JavaScript you need to define components.

The *vue* format is not run directly. It has to be transpiled into plain JavaScript by the Vue-CLI/builder and packed using a packager like [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) first and then loaded by your entry point. Luckily, the [Vue.js CLI handles nearly *all* of this process](https://cli.vuejs.org/) so you can get on with building.

#### File *App.vue*

This is typically the root of your application defined in Vue.js Component file format. It's usually something that defines the template for your page:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <SideBar />
    <router-view v-if="loaded" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SideBar from "./pages/SideBar";

export default {
  components: { SideBar },
  computed: {
    loaded() {
      return this.$store.state.loadState == "loaded";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

#### File *main.js*

This is usually the JavaScript file that will initialise this root component into a element on your page. It is also responsible for setting up plugins and third-party components you may want to use in your app:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import { store } from "./store/store";
import router from "./router";
import App from "./App.vue";

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

#### File *index.html*

The index page provides your entry point in HTML providing an element for Vue.js to load into and imports file *main.js* to initialise your application.

```html
<!-- The HTML element that hosts the App.vue component -->
<div id="app"></div>

<!-- Built files will be auto injected -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

---

On another note, a decent place to put your authentication logic is [in the router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) where you can add navigation guards to restrict access to pages based on the current authentication state and send your users to a login page:

```js
// GOOD
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!isAuthenticated) next('/login')
  else next()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  The Introduction link you recommend doesn't even mention the App.vue file, however.  The Vue docs don't even try to explain how index.html, App.vue, and main.js work together.

Comment: what does ' import Vue from "vue" ' means? where this "vue" element/object is situated in project tree?

Comment: @webuser - that's the import statement that allows you access to the "vue" module using the `Vue` variable/class. Vue is installed using NPM which is a package manager for node projects.

Comment: Seconding Dean's comment, your answer should be in their docs as they just jump right in to writing code without explaining the basics of structure. Like entry point, etc etc

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you specifically need an `index.html` in your project. Provided your `main.js` has an import that references you main Vue page, e.g.:

```
import App from "./App.vue";
```

and then renders it.

```
new Vue({
    ...
    render: (h) => h(App),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The .vue file is a special Vue.js CLI project feature allowing you to write Vue.js apps or Vue.js components in more convenient way. You write your app/component in the .vue file and Vue.js CLI transforms it into code that works in a browser.

The *main.js* in Vue.js CLI project is starting the instance of the app. The *index.html* file in Vue.js CLI project is handled automatically (it's located in the 'public' folder).

The right place to start with Vue.js CLI is: *[Instant Prototyping](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/prototyping.html)*

Comment: This seems to be outdated. Perhaps it is time for an update? But ********************************************************************************************************************************* ***without*** **************************************************************************************************************************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)