# What is the purpose of the 'main.js' file in a Vite.js app?

Tags: javascript, vite

I am building a Vite.js app and am not sure I understand the purpose of the **main.js** file. I am having a hard time finding a clear explanation of this in the [vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#index-html-and-project-root). I found an S/O post with a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972232/what-is-the-purpose-of-main-js-app-vue-in-vue-app) in regards to a Vue app, but am not sure if the answers apply to Vite as well.

I am new to working with these frontend build tools, as well as modules in general, and want to make sure I understand what's happening. I know that **index.html** serves as the entry point to the app during development, but what is the purpose of **main.js** exactly?

My file structure is as follows:

```
├── package.json
├── vite.config.js
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── styles.css
├── pages
│   ├── login
│   │   ├── login.html
│   │   ├── login.js
│   ├── home
│   │   ├── home.html 
│   │   ├── home.js
│   │
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `main.js` you create the app instance, configure it and then mount it to a `div`tag. This is the way forward for any `vue3` application and is independent on the bundling tool used (such as `vite`). A typical example for a `main.js`is as follows:

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'

import store from './store.js'
import router from './routes.js'
import i18n from './i18n.js'
import App from '../components/App.vue'


// mount is the last one ...
const myApp = createApp(App);
myApp.use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(i18n)
    .mount('#app');
```

In the `index.html` you would load this `main.js`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="module" src="/src/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks good, but if I understand correctly, then you answered for Vue and not for Vite.js. Would you have that answer, too?

Comment: I did, see text above: "... is independent on the building tool used (such as vite)"

Comment: my bad. Thanks!