# ViteJS - Why does main.js have HTML?

Tags: vite

I'm new to frontend tooling. I started using Vite and I'm wondering why the `main.js` file has html code in it. It seems like a bad idea to put html in ticks and not have autocomplete, syntax highlighting, and such. I'm used to having an HTML file, or multiple, a CSS file, and a JS file. Is there a way to restructure the files to look like that without losing functionality? If not, should I have a .js file for each page? If so, is there a way to have the html colored and not always look orange?

There's got to be a better way than this:

```
document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = `
  <div>
    <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
      <img src="/vite.svg" class="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript" target="_blank">
      <img src="${javascriptLogo}" class="logo vanilla" alt="JavaScript logo" />
    </a>
    <h1>Hello Dave!</h1>
    <div class="card">
      <button id="counter" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    <p class="read-the-docs">
      Click on the Vite logo to learn more
    </p>
  </div>
`
```

Not the same question as [What is the purpose ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70426620/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-main-js-file-in-a-vite-js-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the main.js file has html code in it.

It's just a demo. And adding HTML dynamically in JS is consistent with other templates using JS frameworks.

> I'm used to having an HTML file, or multiple, a CSS file, and a JS file.

You can just do that. It's completely allowed.

> Is there a way to restructure the files to look like that without losing functionality?

You can just move the HTML to `index.html` and add set that dynamic image src using JS in `main.js`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a thing I'm losing out of by separating the js and html?

Comment: @tazboy No. It's your design choice, and is not quite Vite-related. Vite can well handle both cases.